# Why put parentheses on TestMethod attribute in UnitTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In lots of tutorials for UnitTesting, the way to mark a TestMethod was different. I saw these options:

```
[TestMethod] 
[TestMethod()]
```

What is the difference?

Comment: `[Test]` attribute belongs to `NUnit` Api.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With and without brackets its exactly the same:

```
[TestMethod] 
[TestMethod()]
```

The empty brackets just call the default constructor of that attribute that has no parameters. So does `[TestMethod]`.
Both call the default constructor.

This would be different:

```
[TestMethod(SomeParameter)]
```

And `[Test]` is an attribute that comes from **NUnit** library and is different from the .Net `[TestMethod]` attribute.

Comment: I used some [TestMethod] with parameter and used it in the TestMehod like: actual = target.TextToDouble(textBoxText); So, where and how should i use the SomeParameter? Can you give an example?

Comment: For available parameters & properties check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testmethodattribute.aspx. You could use `[TestMethod(TypeId = "test")]` for example

Answer (score 1):

The empty parentheses are redundant, the two lines are equivalent. Tools such as ReSharper would give you the option of removing this redundancy from your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
[TestMethod] 
[TestMethod()]
```

Both are same but when Visual Studio auto generate test method it comes with `[TestMethod()]`